# iPhone 4s Power Cable Compatibility

Tags: iphone

Can I use an iPhone 4s power cable to charge any other mobile device?

Do any other mobile devices have a power connector similar to the iPhone 4s?

Comment: Do you mean other iPhones? Android devices?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use an iPhone 4s power cable to charge any other mobile device?

Short answer...**YES you can**

The cable is Apple's (legacy) 30 pin connector.

[image]

This cable is compatible with

- iPhone 3G through 4s
- iPad 1st through 3rd Generation
- iPod (various generations)

Apple has a complete and official list of supported devices on their product page: [Apple 30-pin to USB Cable](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MA591G/C/apple-30-pin-to-usb-cable)

Answer (score 1):

<s>I'm not sure what you are asking, especially with your lack of effort in formatting.</s>

The iPhone 4 uses the 30 pin dock connector so devices such as **iPhone (1st generation), iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, 1st through 4th generation iPod Touch, iPad 1, iPad 2, and iPad 3** will support it.

Unless you have a fake (clone) device that also utilises the 30 pin dock connector.